# Entity Class property pointing to navigation property

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to utilize ef core's global query filters and using an interface class (IOwned) to add the OwnerId to all entities that need to be filtered. This works great, but I'd like to extend that to entities that don't directly have the OwnerId field. For instance, the invoice item records of an invoice header. The invoice header has the OwnerId field but the detail records do not. All classes that inherit from IOwned already have the query filter added:

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(t => t.BaseType == null && typeof(IOwned).IsAssignableFrom(t.ClrType)))
{
    entityType.AddQueryFilter<IOwned>(x => x.OwnerId == context.OwnerId);
}
```

I know I can manually call HasQueryFilter and add a navigation property to it (x => x.InvoiceHeader.OwnerId == context.OwnerId), but ideally I'd like the InvoiceItem class to implement the IOwned interface and mark the OwnerId property as NotMapped and that points to the InvoiceHeader OwnerId:

```
public class InvoiceItem : IOwned
{
...

    [NotMapped]
    public int OwnerId => InvoiceHeader.OwnerId;
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work as I get this error:
InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression ... could not be translated

Comment: EF Core is not a compiler (has no access to the source code), so all it sees at runtime (extracted with reflection) is ` public int OwnerId { get; }`, i.e. `int` property called "OwnerId". But it can't see the implementation `=> InvoiceHeader.OwnerId` as it is contaned only in the source code, and then compiled (thus hidden) in the executable. While here `x => x.InvoiceHeader.OwnerId == context.OwnerId` it can see the actual property `x.InvoiceHeader.OwnerId` since it is visible in the expression tree.